# Parse String from string with Regex

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get string from a string with `Regex` :

```
Regex regex = new Regex(".signature=(.*)(", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var v = regex.Match(html);
string funcName = v.Groups[1].Value;
```

This is the a `HTML` string:

```
c&&(b.signature=hj(c));
```

And i want to get the `hj`, and when i run it i get this `exception`:

```
parsing ".signature=(.*)(" - Not enough )'s.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to escape special characters. use this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\.signature=(.*)\(", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var v = regex.Match(html);
string funcName = v.Result("$1");
```

you can find a very good explanation about escaping special characters in regex here (2nd paragraph): http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Edit:

if you search for this specific function in an entire html page, you will have problems, that is because `.*`is greedy, which means it tries to get as much as possbile (see a good explanation about that here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html (3rd paragraph))

a better way would be:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\.signature=([^\(]+)\(", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var v = regex.Match(html);
string funcName = v.Result("$1");
```

`[^\(]+` searches for a string of at least 1 character without a `(`. that would work on an entire html page

Comment: @GrantThomas learn a programming language, and you should know

Comment: What about when _learning_ a language? What about when the languages are mixed?

Comment: @GrantThomas please, write an answer that explains everything, i will upvote it. but i wont explain stuff that anyone (even when learning to program) can find out in a simple google search, probably very well explained

Comment: Well that's your privilege, but doesn't exactly make a remarkable answer.

Comment: @GrantThomas im not trying to be remarkable here, but is it so hard to enter 'escape special characters regex' into a search engine?

Comment: @x4rf41 i try what you suggest and i get a string with another chars from the html and not only the 2 chars

Comment: @MTA if your string is exactly `c&&(b.signature=hj(c));` and you have copy/pasted my code, `funcName` will be `hc`. since you called your string html, is it maybe a much longer string? there might be problems there

Comment: You deserve an upvote not only for the answer, but for dealing with that troll over there.